SQL insert query. Complex locks and concurrency
Based on my tasks I made this synthetic example.
There is a class A which has a class B which has a class C.
public class A
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; } = [];
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid AId { get; set; }
    public A A { get; set; }
    public List<C> Cs { get; set; } = [];
}

public class C
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid BId { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

A request comes in to change class A. The conditions for this are that it must have three classes B, each class B must have one class C whose name starts with a lowercase letter.
I use postgres + EF Core 8.
MainDbContext db1 = ...;
A a = db1.A.first ...;

await using var t1 = await db1.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
a.Name = "Anew";

await db1.SaveChangesAsync();

if (db1.As.Any(m => m.Id == aId && m.Bs.Count() == 3 && m.Bs.All(n => n.Cs.Count == 1 && n.Cs.First().Name == "c")))
    await t1.CommitAsync();
else
    await t1.RollbackAsync();

Now the bottleneck is the time interval between commit and rollback.
Because some other process can break delete/add class B or class C or change class C, which will lead to a false condition.
How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance
I don't know much about SQL and transaction isolation levels, I may have a misconception about some basic things.
I tried the sync isolation level. But for it to work, other requests also need to be executed in the sync isolation level.
Here is all the code I am testing.
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MainDbContext>(m => m.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB")));
var app = builder.Build();
var db1 = app.Services.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainDbContext>();
var db2 = app.Services.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainDbContext>();
var db3 = app.Services.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainDbContext>();
await db3.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
await db3.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
await db3.Database.MigrateAsync();
var aId = Guid.NewGuid();
db3.As.Add(new A()
{
    Id = aId,
    Name = "A",
    Bs =
    [
        new B()
        {
            Cs =
            [
                new C()
                {
                    Name = "c"
                }
            ]
        },
        new B()
        {
            Cs =
            [
                new C()
                {
                    Name = "c"
                }
            ]
        },
        new B()
        {
            Cs =
            [
                new C()
                {
                    Name = "c"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

});
await db3.SaveChangesAsync();

if (Equals(db1, db2))
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
await using var t1 = await db1.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
await using var t2 = await db2.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
var aFromDb1 = await db1.As.Include(m => m.Bs).FirstAsync();
var aFromDb2 = await db2.As.Include(m => m.Bs).FirstAsync();

aFromDb1.Name = "Anew";
await db1.SaveChangesAsync();

db2.Cs.Where(m=> m.BId == db2.Bs.First().Id).ExecuteDelete();
await t2.CommitAsync();

if (db1.As.Any(m => m.Id == aId && m.Bs.Count() == 3 && m.Bs.All(n => n.Cs.Count == 1 && n.Cs.First().Name == "c")))
    await t1.CommitAsync();
else
    await t1.RollbackAsync();

return;


public class MainDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<C> Cs { get; set; }

    public MainDbContext(DbContextOptions<MainDbContext> dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions)
    {
    }
}

public class A
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; } = [];
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid AId { get; set; }
    public A A { get; set; }

    public List<C> Cs { get; set; } = [];
}

public class C
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid BId { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}


What is the actual use case? Could you use a different model to handle this in the database instead? Like having three separate B-properties, and a Notnull constraint?

"the time interval between commit and rollback" - there is no time intervall between commit and rollback. You have either commit or rollback. Never both. So there cannot be any such time intervall between them.

In Postgres, ReadUncommitted doesn't exist. It reverts to the minimum level for Postgres, which is ReadCommitted, which is also the default for a transaction created by BeginTransaction. It means that a query queries the current state of the database at the time of the query, which I guess is what you want. Higher isolation reads the state at the start of the transaction. Whatever you do, in the end these concurrency conflicts should always be solved by deciding if a transaction just fails, or the process should be retried.

Ah, you mean the start of the transaction ... now I get it, nevermind. Maybe phrase that a little clearer.

"Because some other process can break delete/add class B or class C or change class C, which will lead to a false condition." are you aware of an actual issue, or is this juts your presumed conclusion?

Yes, this is the expected conclusion. Unfortunately, I do not have the opportunity to upload all the sources. I only simplified the model to a minimal state.
In general, the question looks like this.
I need to perform an operation and validate it. The problem is that validation affects not only the update of certain rows, but also insertion into other tables. That is, I cannot simply block the update of 3 records B and 3 records C, I need to block the insertion into table B with a foregein key AId and block the insertion into table C with a foregein key BId

It is possible to override SaveChanges and keep in A concurrency token even children are updated, inserted, deleted. Then your will not need any explicit transactions, optimistic concurrency will work automatically. Simplfied sample is here, but here OP wants to update only modified date.

SaveChanges and the tracker will work only for the current request. The request may be different, respectively, and the scope and the DB context will be different. Moreover, this may happen in another service instance

Probably you do not understand what is Optimistic concurrency, especially Application-managed concurrency tokens

Idea is that in single SaveChanges batch you change your Concurrency Token even if children are changed (Aggregation root) and EF will check automatically that no one else not changed similar Aggregation root while you preparing your new save batch.

Apparently I misunderstood you. Yes, I have Handling Concurrency implemented. I could change the token for all entities participating in the validation. But the problem remains that I need to block the insertion of certain records into the table. Here I think to consider the possibility of inserting RULE for the table inside the transaction

You do not understand again. I mean not tokens of all entities but token for entity A, if in ChangeTraker, you have insert of children of entity A - modify Concurrency token of Entiry A, If you have insert into children of entity B - again modify Concurrency token of entity A.

Now I understand. Thanks, cool solution.
